# Dynamically Selecting Map in Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, x12

I am trying to build a logic app that receives incoming X12 EDI messages.  I have an integration account set up and an agreement created.  However, I don't see a way to associate a map with an agreement.  It seems I have to hard code this in the logic app which would mean one logic app for each trading partner document type.  Surely there is a way to select maps based on sender, receiver and document type.  This is basic functionality for other EDI packages but I don't have a clue with logic apps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether there is a better way, but you can specify the map name at run time. 
Then, as you are already using an integration account, you can externalise Business Rule using liquid templates, as explained here: https://blog.mexia.com.au/business-rules-on-azure-logic-apps-with-liquid-templates

You could pass some metadata about the trading partner to the liquid template, and then return the name of the map and use it in the mapping action.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is almost as easy as BizTalk Server* ;)

Since the Map Name can be composed at runtime, you can upload your Maps using a set pattern, for example [SenderID] + "_" + [MessageType] -> "CONTOSOSID_810"

Then Initialize a Variable set to [SenderID] + "_" + [MessageType] and use that as the Map parameter to the Liquid Action.

Important Point: Every output of the X12 Decoder can loop so you may have to manually index the paths in the Initialize Variable depending on if/how you're debatching the transactions.

*BizTalk Server automatically resolved the Map based on the Party's message Type which you could use here, just that the names are a bit messy.